# Unrecognized token 'transaction_id' in PayPal request

Tags: paypal, python-requests, request

I feel like theres just some syntax I'm doing wrong on my part and can't find any solutions.

```
    url = 'https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/shipping/trackers/%s-%s' % (paypal_transaction_token, tracking_number)
    print("url is", url)

    headers = {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % access_token,
    }
    print('headders here', headers)

    data = {
        "transaction_id": "%s" % paypal_transaction_token,
        "tracking_number":"%s" % tracking_number,
        "status": "%s" % status,
        "carrier": "%s" % carrier
    }
    print("data", data)

    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

The error I keep receiving is `Unrecognized token 'transaction_id'` and if I remove transaction_id I just get the same error for whichever data param is first.

According to the docs, this is all correct so I assume its on my code that is wrong:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/tracking/integrate/#update-or-cancel-tracking-information
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/tracking/v1/

What in my code is wrong?

I have tried without the `%s` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error I keep receiving is Unrecognized token 'transaction_id' and if I remove transaction_id I just get the same error for whichever data param is first.

`requests.put` will *form encode* the data, while the PayPal API
accepts JSON. Do:

```
data=json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.  I'm now having more issues with the actual tracking_id.  Paypal is giving me ` {"name":"INVALID_TRACKING_NUMBER","message":"The requested resource ID was not found","debug_id":"1324","details":[{"field":"tracker_id","value":"1234-1234","location":"path","issue":"INVALID_TRACKING_INFO"}],"links":[]}` even though the transaction_id and tracking_id are live and real